# How to force HTTPS in nextjs App without creating a custom server

Tags: reactjs, https, next.js

Does someone know how to force HTTPS in nextjs without creating a custom server?

UPDATE 1:

my current solution is by doing this in a HOC:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.protocol !== 'https:'
     && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') router.push(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FRONT_BASE_URL + window.location.pathname);
  }, [])
```

i'm hoping to find a better way.

UPDATE 2:

i ended up switching to Vercel, i found it much better than heroku.

Comment: Are you wanting to use a serverless setup on Vercel?

Comment: i'm using heroku for hosting actually

Comment: switch over to Vercel and it forces https for you.

Comment: i tried it and i enjoyed it so much, i've decided to switch all my 3 front apps there, it works like a charm, thank you @Matt

Comment: Oh cool! Glad I could help.

Comment: is it your solution 1 still relevant? and I wanna asking about where's your put this HOC function in nextjs? in _app.js?

Comment: Use ngrok, very easy to use tool to make local port available online via https. Method explained here: https://frontendguruji.com/blog/run-next-js-app-locally-in-https/